# How can edit body message email template by Plugin

Tags: c#, email, templates, plugins, dynamics-crm-2016

How can I edit an E-mail template Body by plugin in CRM 2016?

The Template already exist, I retrieve the Template ID by code plugin, and I want edit the  message body by plugin.

To retrieve the message body email template I use the 'description' attribute.
and if I want to update the body email template with this attribute, with 'description', this updated the description box not the body message.

The following code describes receiving an e-mail template, how can update the message body by this Template?

```
private Entity GetTemplateByName(IOrganizationService client, string templateName)
{
    var query = new QueryExpression();
    query.EntityName ="template";

    var filter = new FilterExpression();
    var condition1 = new ConditionExpression("title", ConditionOperator.Equal, new object[] { templateName });
    filter.AddCondition(condition1);

    query.Criteria = filter;

    EntityCollection allTemplates = client.RetrieveMultiple(query);

    Entity emailTemplate = null;

    if (allTemplates.Entities.Count > 0)            
    {
        emailTemplate = allTemplates.Entities[0];

    }
    return emailTemplate;
}
```

Comment: You need to modify the `body` attribute, not `description`.

Comment: As it looks, you do not know how to handle a templates' body, so it might be worth to ask what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

From the SDK, the **Template** entity has an attribute called **body** which is described as:

> Body text of the email template

**body** has an AttributeTypeCode of AttributeType.Memo, which is a string.

You should be able to simply use:

```
emailTemplate["body"] = "Some new email template body.";
```

Comment: the body of email template can not to get a string value.i try to update the body email template with string value and  i got the following error: xslXml is template body .